# Google sites + custom domain DNS configuration

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registrar, google-sites

I have a google site and I have a domain. The domain is registered with GoDaddy and points to DreamHost (I host other sites on this DH account so it is not dedicated for this site). Because it's a google site, the Dreamhost domain just has index.html which redirects to the google site:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <META http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=https://sites.google.com/view/.../home"></HEAD>
    <BODY>
        Redirecting...
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

However, this does not show the domain. To accomplish that, I need to verify the domain ownership:

[image]

But when I click "verify your ownership," the subsequent verification process instructions are confusing. The verification process asks "who is your domain provider?"

[image]

I assume by "domain provider" it means registrar, because GoDaddy is on the list and DreamHost is not. However, the subsequent instruction says to add a TXT record to the domain:

[image]

This option is available in DreamHost, but not in GoDaddy:

GoDaddy domain DNS console (no TXT record option present):
[image]

DreamHost console (TXT option present):
[image]

But when I add the TXT record in Dreamhost, waited days for it to propogate, I get this error in google sites:

> Verification failed for www.********.org using the DNS TXT record method (less than a minute ago). Your verification DNS TXT record was not found. You might need to wait a few minutes before Google sees your changes to the TXT records.

How do I proceed?

Note: I would prefer to keep DreamHost as the domain manager for the sake of email, but it is not that important. If I need to cut DreamHost out of this loop that is ok.

Comment: Since you're using DreamHost nameservers, DreamHost is definitely the place to add that TXT record. Make sure you're adding TXT to `www` as Google wants, not to the bare domain.

Comment: Wow! The missing `www` was the key! Thanks. Leave it as an answer and I'll give the check mark

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're adding your TXT record to `www` as Google wants, not just to the bare domain.